# How ot rotatearound the transform object around the target on other axis x and z with random height?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RotateAroundTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 axisToRotate;
    public float verticalSpeed = 20;
    public float radius = 10;
    public bool moveToRadius = false;

    private float targetHeight;
    private float oldRadius;
    private bool moveToRadiusCoroutineOnce = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // Initialize with a height to start moving toward
        targetHeight = GetNewTargetHeight();

        // If we start at a given distance away from the target, then this
        // will become our radius when we RotateAround it
        oldRadius = radius;
        if (moveToRadius == false)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, radius);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(moveToRadius && moveToRadiusCoroutineOnce)
        {
            StartCoroutine(MoveTo(new Vector3(0,0,radius), 5f));

            moveToRadiusCoroutineOnce = false;
        }

        if(radius != oldRadius)
        {
            //transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, radius);
            oldRadius = radius;
            moveToRadiusCoroutineOnce = true;
        }

        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,
            axisToRotate, 20 * Time.deltaTime);

        // Just like your rotation rate, we scale this based on game time
        float maxHeightChange = verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        float targetHeightDelta = targetHeight - transform.position.z;

        if (maxHeightChange >= Mathf.Abs(targetHeightDelta))
        {
            // If the current height is close enough to the target, we can move it
            // there and then generate a new height to go towards
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x,
                targetHeight,
                transform.position.z);
            targetHeight = GetNewTargetHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise, limit the magnitude of the height change by the speed and
            // apply it to the current height
            float allowedHeightChange = Mathf.Clamp(
                targetHeightDelta,
                -maxHeightChange,
                maxHeightChange);
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x,
                transform.position.y + allowedHeightChange,
                transform.position.z);
        }
    }

    private float GetNewTargetHeight()
    {
        return Random.Range(0, 5f);
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveTo(Vector3 endPos, float moveDurationInSeconds)
    {
        var fromPosition = transform.position;
        var toPosition = endPos;

        // looks strange but as long as you yield somewhere inside
        // the loop it simply means repeat the sequence forever
        // just like the Update method
        while (true)
        {
            var passedTime = 0f;

            while (passedTime < moveDurationInSeconds)
            {
                var lerpFactor = passedTime / moveDurationInSeconds;
                // and now add ease-in and ease-out
                var smoothedLerpFactor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, lerpFactor);

                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(fromPosition, toPosition, smoothedLerpFactor);

                passedTime += Mathf.Min(moveDurationInSeconds - passedTime, Time.deltaTime);

                // reads like: "pause" here, render this frame and continue
                // from here in the next frame
                yield return null;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the variable axisToRotate and using it in the line :

```
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,
            axisToRotate, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

before the line was :

```
transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position,
            new Vector3(0,1,0), 20 * Time.deltaTime);
```

and if i'm setting in the inspector the axisToRotate to 0,1,0 it's working fine.  the transform is changing the height randomaly and rotating in horizontal around the target.

but now I want to be able also to change the rotation to vertical around the target with the random height.

if I'm changing the axisToRotate to 0,0,1 and not using the height part it will rotate around the target vertical fine but if I'm using the height part it will move the transform far from the target and will not rotate around the target at all.

I tried to change the variable axisToRotate in the inspector to 0,0,1 but then it's moving the transfrom away from the target.

Comment: Ah, I see you've made a new question for this. So to clarify - you'd like the object to rotate vertically around the target, but you'd also like it's height to be changed randomly? If that's the case, are you looking to vary the radius of the circle of rotation, or the height of its center (which I presume would start in line with the target object)?

Comment: the height of its center , so the target is the center. right.

Comment: Is this really different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442057/how-to-make-object-rotate-around-target-with-random-height-and-with-option-to-ch)? It's still quite unclear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve here ... Maybe some illustrations would help